# Multiple React Apps in a single LoadBalancer on GKE

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to deploy 2 different react apps (exposed as Nodeport services) in a single kubernetes cluster. Exposing them on separate ingresses work fine and i see the react page for each. i.e. for service web1

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress-1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web1
          servicePort: 5000
```

Same works with `serviceName: web2`. However, Trying to merge both as a fanout ingress only shows one of the services (web1):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web1
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /web2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: web2
          servicePort: 5000
```

Is it possible to expose 2 react apps on a single Ingress?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible but I think your second path (path: /web2/*) will be ignored since the first one (path: /*) routes everything after / to web1. Try changing the first route to something like (path: /web1/*). Something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /web1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: web1
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /web2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: web2
          servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: `your second path (path: /web2/) will be ignored since the first one (path: /) routes everything after / to web1` -> No, the longer path will match.